# How to set a ringtone with unknown attributes?

Tags: android, ringtone

I'm currently trying to set a sound as a ringtone. I saw several example using the following code : 
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/a.mp3";

```
   File k = new File(path, "a.mp3");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "A");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 210341);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    // Insert it into the database
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri newUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(FirstActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```

There are several things that I'm struggling with : 
for this line :  `values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 210341);` how can I do to find the size without giving the size directly ? 
Same question with the duration line :  `values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);`
(I want to set the size and the duration dynamically) 
And is it a problem if you don't fill these values ?